# Can't show image into image slider in Laravel blade template

Tags: php, image, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

My image is inside `public/storage/slider-images/February2018` location. I retrieve the image name from database but can't show image into my blade template in Laravel though the image is there.

Here is my code of image part in home.blade.php file

```
@foreach($sliderImage as $data) 
    {{ HTML::image('public/storage/'.$data->default_img) }}"
@endforeach
```

And output is `http://localhost:8000/public/storage/slider-images/February2018/k8X3qSaqjIYAVYcqapMr.jpg`

This url is also not correctly opened in the browser if Itry to open it on the separate tab.

what's the problem in the code ?

Comment: What is the exact output, is an image tag generated and its source value set? And is the html what you need it to be for your slider? You should take a look at the source in the browser.

Comment: are you using symbolic link ?

Comment: @jeroen I tried with image tag but also didn't get the result. Image was not showing in the slider

Comment: I am not using symlink @JeuneGuerrier

Comment: http://localhost:8000/public/storage/slider-images/February2018/k8X3qSaqjIYAVYcqapMr.jpg - is this url correctly opened in the browser if you try to open it on the separate tab?

Comment: @Pavel I also tried this process. But not opened in the browser also. I should have told this in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got my answer.

```
<img src="storage/{{ $data->default_img }}"
```

And noted that.

**Images should be in `public` folder.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet:

```
 @foreach($sliderImage as $data) 
          $image_location=$data['image_location']; //your image location from db or array
// $image_location = storage/slider-images/February2018/imagename.jpg
          <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}{{ $image_location }}"     
    @endforeach
```

Comment: didn't work. If I am using this all the image is come together. @syed mahroof

Comment: can you check without public in url ? http://localhost:8000/storage/slider-images/Febru?ary2018/k8X3qSaqjIYAVYcqapMr.jpg is your browser and getting image?